# getting error when invoking trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, function, triggers

I have created a trigger in mysql that is to be invoked immediately after a row is updated in a table.

And I'm getting this error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'users_leave_balance' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I have noticed that on invoking trigger to the same table produces this result and BEFORE timing is encouraged with NEW and OLDs, but I'm still getting this error.

Here's the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_balance_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON users_leave_balance
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE users_leave_balance
    SET rollable_till_date = getRollableValue(new.period, new.user_id)
    WHERE user_id = new.user_id AND period = new.period AND leave_type = new.leave_type; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A little picture of what I'm trying to do.

```
user_id  | period     |  leave_type  |  leave_taken  |  rollable_till_date
134      | 2017-01-01 |  2           |  5.00         |  3.00
134      | 2017-02-01 |  1           |  3.5          |  2.00 (value excluding 3.5)
```

Value in rollable_till_date column is computed by 'getRollableValue(date, userID)' function and it requires values from 'leave_taken' field.

The problem is when updating a record, value to rollable_till_date is calculated but the current value of "leave_taken" is excluded, but which is also required.

Here's the update query:

```
UPDATE users_leave_balance 
SET leave_taken = (leave_taken + $leaveTaken), 
rollable_till_date = (SELECT getRollableValue('$period', $userid))
WHERE user_id = $userID AND period = '$period' AND leave_type = $leaveType
```

Therefore, I intended to use trigger on this, so that all values are excluded and computed accordingly.

I know this went off-topic, but I seriously need some help on this.
Any help is very much appreciated thanks. :)

Comment: Generally a trigger on update triggers do not tend to "update" their own table via a query, my suggestion is to use a before update trigger, and use the "new"/"old"  words to modify the "new" values , knowing the old ones, and letting the update finish its work.

Comment: @Gar I have made changes to the trigger and also updated the post. But I'm getting error now.